# Valueerror for reshaping array for image entropy

Tags: python, arrays, rgb, valueerror, entropy

I have a code for finding entropy info of an image by resizing the image and dividing it into its RGB channels.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread
import cv2
import imageio
#读取RGB图像
def openRGB(image_path):
    f =  open(image_path,"rb")
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    data = [int(x) for x in data]
    data = np.array(data).reshape((256*256, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
    return data
def entropy(X):
    n = len(X)
    counts = np.bincount(X)
    probs = counts[np.nonzero(counts)] / n
   en = 0
   for i in range(len(probs)):
       en = en - probs[i] * np.log(probs[i])/np.log(2)
   return en
def getEntropy(image_path):
   data =openRGB(image_path)
   data_B = data[:, 0]
   data_G = data[:, 1]
   data_R = data[:, 2]
   B = entropy(data_B)
   G = entropy(data_G)
   R = entropy(data_R)
   return (R+B+G)/2;
```

However, whenever I run the getentropy() function on a given image it keeps giving back this error

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 37048 into shape (65536,3)

Any idea how I can reformat the image to fit that array shape?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple explanation: `image_path` length in bytes is only `37048`.

When using `np.array(data).reshape((256*256, 3))`, the length of `data` must be `256*256*3` = `196608` bytes.

You are getting an exception because the lengths do not match.

---

It's simple to reproduce the problem.

- Create an input sample file in size `196608` bytes, and there is no exception.
- Create an input sample file in size `37048` bytes, get an exception.

Here is a code sample that reproduces the problem:

```
import os
#from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
#from scipy.misc import imread
#import cv2
#import imageio

def openRGB(image_path):
    f = open(image_path, "rb")
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    data = [int(x) for x in data]
    data = np.array(data).reshape((256*256, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
    return data

def entropy(X):
    n = len(X)
    counts = np.bincount(X)
    probs = counts[np.nonzero(counts)] / n
    en = 0
    for i in range(len(probs)):
        en = en - probs[i] * np.log(probs[i])/np.log(2)
    return en

def getEntropy(image_path):
    data = openRGB(image_path)
    data_B = data[:, 0]
    data_G = data[:, 1]
    data_R = data[:, 2]
    B = entropy(data_B)
    G = entropy(data_G)
    R = entropy(data_R)
    return (R+B+G)/2


# Create a binary file with random bytes
image_path = 'tmp.bin'

# When n_bytes=196608, there is no exception.
################################################################################
n_bytes = 256*256*3

tmp = np.random.randint(0, 255, n_bytes, np.uint8)  # Build random array of n_bytes bytes
with open(image_path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tmp)  # Write tmp to a binary file

file_size_in_bytes = os.path.getsize(image_path)
print('file_size_in_bytes = ' + str(file_size_in_bytes))

res = getEntropy(image_path)
print(res)
################################################################################


# When n_bytes=37048, an exception is raised: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 37048 into shape (65536,3)
################################################################################
n_bytes = 37048
tmp = np.random.randint(0, 255, n_bytes, np.uint8)  # Build random array of n_bytes bytes
with open(image_path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tmp)  # Write tmp to a binary file

file_size_in_bytes = os.path.getsize(image_path)
print('file_size_in_bytes = ' + str(file_size_in_bytes))

res = getEntropy(image_path)
print(res)
################################################################################
```

---

**Why are you reading `37048` bytes instead of `196608` bytes?**

`image_path` is a JPEG image file, and you are reading the image using `f = open(image_path, "rb")` and `data = f.read()`.

You may read and reshape the image as follows:

```
import cv2

def openRGB(image_path):
    # For example: image_path = 'img.jpg'
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)  # Read image in BGR color format.
    data = np.array(img).reshape(img.shape[0]*img.shape[1], 3)  # Reshape to rows x cols x 3 (Blue in data[:, 0], green in data[:, 1], red in data[:, 2]).

    return data
```

In the above example I used `img.shape[0]*img.shape[1]`, the image resolution is:

```
height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]
```

Comment: Its actually  a set of 8 separate jpg images and I am trying to get the individual entropy figures from each of them. Hence do I adjust the reshape() function according to each individual image before runtime or am I missing something else？

Comment: Instead of `256*256` you may use: `data = np.array(img).reshape(img.shape[0]*img.shape[1], 3)`. Each JPEG image is RGB right? In case it is Grayscale, the solution is different.

Comment: I updated my answer - reimplementing `openRGB(image_path)`